# RequireJS and TypeScript name.d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, tfs, requirejs

I am trying to load the rest clients to use in a custom Azure Devops Dashboard Widget. In the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2?view=azure-devops) it show's the typescript example of

```
import RestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");

// Get an instance of the client
var client = RestClient.getClient();

// Call a method on the client
// e.g. client.getResource(...).then(...);
```

to load a rest client. I attempted to follow this example and have put what I think should be a working code example below.

However, when the page loads, I get the following errors,

```
require.js:1961 GET https://localhost:5500/scripts/node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
require.js:1961 GET https://localhost:5500/scripts/node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts/WorkItemTracking/RestClient.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
require.js:1961 GET https://localhost:5500/scripts/node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts/WorkItemTracking/Contracts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

For some reason, RequireJS appears to be trying to load javascript files for the types defined in the `tfs.d.ts` file.

I am aware that [`VSS.require()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=azure-devops#method_require) can be used, but I would like to try and use the format shown in the documentation.

Does anyone know what I am missing or how I can change it to fix this problem with loading the modules with RequireJS?

---

**Edit**

I forgot to mention, the library I am using is called the [VSS Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk). I installed it via the npm command, `npm install vss-web-extension-sdk`. The reason I am trying to use RequireJS with this library is because in the TypeScript section of the README, it points to using the AMD module.

---

Required code and config files

*Test.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="scripts/config.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="widget">
            <h2 class="title"></h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*config.js*

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "VSS": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js",
        "TFS": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts"
    }
});
require(["HelloWorld"]);
```

Note: When the line `"TFS": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts"` is not there, the following errors are shown.

```
require.js:1961 GET https://localhost:5500/scripts/TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
require.js:1961 GET https://localhost:5500/scripts/TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
require.js:1961 GET https://localhost:5500/scripts/TFS/WorkItemTracking/Contracts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

*HelloWorld.ts*

```
VSS.init({                        
    explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
    usePlatformStyles: true
});

import WidgetHelpers = require("TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers");
import RestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");
import { QueryExpand } from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/Contracts";

// Get an instance of the client
var client = RestClient.getClient();
WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();

VSS.register("HelloWorldWidget", function () {                
    return {
        load: function (widgetSettings) {
            var $title = $('h2.title');
            $title.text('Hello World');
            console.log(client.getQueries("Projects", QueryExpand.All));

            return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
        }
    };
});
VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
```

Compiled *HelloWorld.js*

```
define(["require", "exports", "TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/Contracts"], function (require, exports, WidgetHelpers, RestClient, Contracts_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformStyles: true
    });
    // Get an instance of the client
    var client = RestClient.getClient();
    WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
    VSS.register("HelloWorldWidget", function () {
        return {
            load: function (widgetSettings) {
                var $title = $('h2.title');
                $title.text('Hello World');
                console.log(client.getQueries("Projects", Contracts_1.QueryExpand.All));
                return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
            }
        };
    });
    VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
});
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "scripts",
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "types": [
            "vss-web-extension-sdk"
        ]    
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think *RequireJS* is what they expect you to use? I followed the link to the documentation you provided in your question, searched for "RequireJS" there but found no hit.

Comment: @Louis That's a good point. I should have included a little more information. I assumed that it was using RequireJS as the [README](https://github.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/master/README.md) for the extension library, in the TypeScript section, it shows the module they use is AMD. After some research, that seemed to point to using RequireJS. I'm afraid I'm still quite new to both this library and TypeScript so please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Louis Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm extremely familiar with RequireJS but not familiar at all with Azure and TFS. I'm pretty sure what you need to do is to use `VSS.require` to kick off the execution of your code. (Note that you don't need to change the calls to `require` in your TypeScript code.) Unfortunately, I cannot easily test any of this because I don't have the proper setup at hand.

Comment: @Louis You are right about being able to use VSS.require to start the extension running. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906307/louis) said, this can be done by using `VSS.require` to start everything.

My code currently looks a bit like this.

The Widget HTML file.

```
<head>
    <script src="../lib/VSS_Web_Extension/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../compiled_ts/WidgetInit.js"></script>
</head>
```

*WidgetInit.js*

```
// Initialize the VSS sdk
VSS.init({
    explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
    usePlatformScripts: true,
    usePlatformStyles: true
});

// Wait for the SDK to be initialized
VSS.ready(function () {
    //All my other code is in Widget.js and runs fine
    VSS.require(["src/compiled_ts/Widget"]);
});
```

Comment: thank you, costed me like thre days to make any library work. Funny thing was that jquery was working out of the box with cdn include but jquery.column only works with require.